# Backward compatibility with JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a java application which saves the fields of an object to a file and load them later again.

I used so far a modified version of `java.util.properties.Properties` file (the properties were written in the order they were put in the properties object). I defined for each field a property-key and use the following function to set the property in the properties object

```
properties.setProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_FIELD_X, field_x);
```

and used the following function if I want to read back from the properties file

```
field_x = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_FIELD_X, ""));
```

where I can add a default value which will be choosed, when there is no property with the specified key. As I maybe add some fields in the future in the class from which the fields were saved in the file, I used this option with the default value to set a field to some defined value for the case I load a properties file which was written with an older version of this class.

So far it works but with some obvious disadvantage, for example I can't use the same property key more than once, I have to add some kind of indices like `1_PROPERTY_KEY`, `2_PROPERTY_KEY`. Thats why I came across JSON.

I'm not very familiar with JSON and all the things we can achieve with it. But I know I could use it to save the fields of an object to the JSON notation and read it back for example with Gson

```
//Object to JSON
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(object);

//JSON to Object
object = gson.fromJson(json);
```

But I assume this will fail, if the class is a newer version (i.e. some new fields) when try to read back from the JSON. How can I treat this? Do I have to take care of every seperate field similar to the the current implementation with properties? For example like this (with `com.google.gson`), assuming `jsonString` is the string read from the file:

```
//try/catch block omitted
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONElement json = parser.parse(jsonString);
field_x = json.getAsString("field_x");
```

and take care if something failed to set default values to the fields?

Or is there a completely different approach without JSON or is JSON in general suitable for my use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert of JSON too. But I used it sometimes with [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) and I think Gson is very similar. If you want to use versioned objects just assure in your object constructor that fields are given with a default value (outside correct values range). Jackson will match only those json fields where it finds a correspondent filed in th Java object. Otherwise the default value is kept.

Comment: Well that sounds what I'm looking for. Could you give me a small example how this will work in general?

Answer (score 2):

With GSON, you get to define your model as an object.  As an example:

```
public class Configuration
{
  private String x;

  private String y;
}
```

Later, you may adjust `Configuration` to have an additional field, `z`:

```
public class Configuration
{
  private String x;

  private String y;

  private String z;
}
```

When you use GSON to deserialise your JSON file that does not contain a value for `z`, it will be left `null` (or whatever the Java default value for that type is).

Since you have an object, you can define getters that substitute a default value if one is not specified:

```
public String getZ()
{
  if (this.z == null)
  {
    return "the default z value";
  }

  return this.z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not goind to send data across network, I think you don't need Json but use native Java classes (ie properties). It's reduntant object creation

Comment: One requirement which I should mention is that the file should be readable. Or what did you mean with native Java classes?